# Using 3 Channel Video Switcher Module with Arduino

Tags: arduino, switches, dc, pwm, video

Hey all I am wondering how to go about switch from camera 1, 2 or 3 using this 3 Channel Video Switcher Module on [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-Channel-3-Way-Video-Switcher-Module-for-FPV-Camera-/311178902555?pt=Radio_Control_Parts_Accessories&hash=item4873b53c1b) here.
[image]

Since there's only V+, V- and signal for the "switch" it looks to take a PWM but I am not quite sure if that's correct or not. If correct then how would I (in code) send that out for each camera to change?

**UPDATE**

Well I've tried the following code:

```
int LED_pin = 9; // must be one of 3, 5, 6, 9, 10 or 11 for PWM

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_pin, OUTPUT); // Initialize pin for output
}

void loop() {
  int dtwait = 1000; // Pause interval, milliseconds
  int V1=20, V2=220, V3=120; // 8-bit output values for PWM duty cycle
  analogWrite(LED_pin, V1);
  delay(dtwait);
  analogWrite(LED_pin, V2);
  delay(dtwait);
  analogWrite(LED_pin, V3);
  delay(dtwait);
}
```

and just to test it I hooked up 2 green LEDs to digital pin 9 and I can confirm it does light the led's in 3 stages. From bright, medium and then dim-ish.

So I went ahead and powered up the FPV by hooking it up like so:
[image]

One looks like it says P15V 331QE BZ10
[image]

While the other side has one that maybe says STC 15F104E F-4V938.A
[image]

What could I be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Ask the supplier for a datasheet, and/or find the datasheet for the IC used on the board. (And don't buy things if the supplier doesn't provide adequate documentation.)

Comment: Updated my OP to show code and my connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I got it.

Using the **#include  Servo library** I was able to get the following values confirmed that switched the video input:

```
cam1 = 0-64 and also 153-180
cam2 = 65-123
cam3 = 124-152
```

The arduino code looks like this:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;
int pos = 0;

void setup()
{
  myservo.attach(9);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  for(pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees 
  {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    Serial.println(pos);
    delay(1000);                     // waits 1 minute so i can see the value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a very similar switch with an Arduino (to generate the PWM signal).
Have a look here:

http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1955631

Comment: Can you simplify that posting with just the needed code for switching to either video1, video2 or video3 using the digital pin 3 PWM? Lots of information on that site with a lot more code than i really am in need of. Thanks!